# How to fill remaining height and width?

Tags: html, css

I'm an experienced .net developer, but all of us have areas where we can benefit from improvements. I feel that I'm severely lacking in HTML/CSS skills and I'm trying to teach myself in this area.

I'm trying to create an HTML layout for an application that monitors bandwidth consumption on the local network. I envisage the layout as consisting of 4 elements:

```
+--------------------------+
+ Controls                 +
+--------+-----------------+
+ Legend +  Graph          +
+        +                 +
+        +                 +
+        +                 +
+        +                 +
+--------+-----------------+
+ Log                      +
+--------------------------+
```

- **Controls** - this is a narrow area that will allow clear, pause and otherwise control the graph. It will also allow to show and hide log area. This means that the layout need to accommodate the log area being hidden.
- **Legend** - is a `table` that will list all series on the graph. It will show series color and also some numeric data associated with the series. If there are more lines in the legend that fit the screen it should be possible to vertical scroll legend area. Horizontal scroll is never required for the area it's assumed that it is always narrow enough. The `height` of Legend (and Graph) should take up all the remaining space that is not used by Control area and Log area. The `width` of the legend will be equal to the natural `table` `width`.
- **Graph** - there will be a Graph here painted over HTML `canvas`. This should take up all available space both horizontally and vertically.
- **Log** - here will be two or three lines of log displayed. If there are more than 3 lines to display there should be a vertical scroll bar on this area. This area need to be able to be hid-able. The `height` of this area can be made fixed. (in the vicinity of `100px` - `200px`).

The layout should adapt to window re-sizing, and keep looking descent when windows is being made small (to a point of course). Unless the window is too small, it should not have outer horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

Unfortunately, I cannot get it right in several places.

This is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      * {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
      html, button, input, select, textarea {
          font-family: sans-serif;
          font-weight: 100;
          letter-spacing: 0.01em;
      }
      .container {
        min-height:100%;
        position:relative;
      }
      .control {
          background:green;
          width:100%;
          height:auto;
          margin-top: 0;
      }
      .content {
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        margin-top:0;
        margin-bottom:0;
      }
      .legend {
        position:relative;
        background:blue;
        float:left
      }
      .graph {
        background:red;

      }
      .log {
        background:yellow;
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        position:absolute;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
      }
      .table {
          border-collapse: collapse;
          border-spacing: 0;
          empty-cells: show;
          border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
      }
      .table td,
      .table th {
          border-left: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
          border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
          font-size: inherit;
          margin: 0;
          overflow: visible;
          padding: 0.5em 1em; 
      }
      .table thead {
          background-color: #e0e0e0;
          color: #000;
          text-align: left;
          vertical-align: bottom;
      }
      .table td {
          background-color: transparent;
      }
      .table-odd td {
          background-color: #f2f2f2;
      }
    </style>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="control">header1<br/>header2</div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="legend">
          <table class="table">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>#</th>
                      <th>Make</th>
                      <th>Model</th>
                      <th>Year</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr class="table-odd">
                      <td style="background-color: #FFB300">1</td>
                      <td>Honda</td>
                      <td>Accord</td>
                      <td>2009</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td style="background-color: #803E75">2</td>
                      <td>Toyota</td>
                      <td>Camry</td>
                      <td>2012</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="table-odd">
                      <td style="background-color: #FF6800">3</td>
                      <td>Hyundai</td>
                      <td>Elantra</td>
                      <td>2010</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td style="background-color: #A6BDD7">4</td>
                      <td>Ford</td>
                      <td>Focus</td>
                      <td>2008</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="table-odd">
                      <td style="background-color: #C10020">5</td>
                      <td>Nissan</td>
                      <td>Sentra</td>
                      <td>2011</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td style="background-color: #CEA262">6</td>
                      <td>BMW</td>
                      <td>M3</td>
                      <td>2009</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr class="table-odd">
                      <td style="background-color: #817066">7</td>
                      <td>Honda</td>
                      <td>Civic</td>
                      <td>2010</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td style="background-color: #007D34">8</td>
                      <td>Kia</td>
                      <td>Soul</td>
                      <td>2010</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="graph"><canvas></canvas></div>
      </div>  
      <div class="log">log1<br/>log2</div>
    </div>
    <script>
      function resize() {
        var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        canvas.style.width = '100%';
        canvas.style.height = '100%';
        canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
        canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.strokeStyle='yellow';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.stroke();
        }
      resize();
      window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the corresponding [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6n119d24/)

Particular problems that I'm facing:

- Why `canvas` is being rendered outside of the enclosing `div`? This is very surprising to me and I cannot figure out why.
- How do I make the `table` be spaced out naturally? In particular:

  - Why first line is so tall?
  - How do I make the `table` do not take the whole `height`? It's enclosing dive that has `height:100%`, not the table, so why is it so tall?
  - How do I make it scroll-able if it's does not fit in the `height`?
- The Legend/Graph area seems to extend underneath the Log area. Why? How do I prevent that?
- Finally, how can I make the Log area of fixed height and scroll-able?

My apologies, I know that this question is a tall order, I'll gratefully accept any help and/or pointers. I do realize that I lack basic understanding, but that's what I'm trying to work against. I spent most of the evening today researching this topic and looking for source that allowed me to put together at least this non-working example. I'm comfortable with JavaScript, it's HTML/CSS that I mainly need help with. I studied the documentation on what properties of different DOM objects do, but it's difficult to figure out *what* properties to use and how.

Comment: have you looked into flexbox for page layouts?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use flexbox for this? It seems like you are heavily over-engineering your layout. I'd also advise against using HTML tables at all, they are unpredictable and it's pretty terrible to modify their default behaviour. When in doubt, stick to divs.

Comment: @Senthe According to [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) flexbox has a lot of bugs in IE11 and does not work at all on previous IEs. While I'm not aiming to support all browsers from beginning  of the time, excluding IE completely is definitely something that I'd like to avoid. Thank you for the tip about flexbox, though,never heard of it before - so I learned something - I'll read up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are complicating your CSS a lot for what you want,

you can use `CSS Flexbox` along with `CSS calc()` for this

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
section {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}
article {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px)
}
aside,
div {
  background: lightblue;
}
aside {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-width: 45%
}
aside ~ div {
  flex: 1
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green
}
.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.column {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-left: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
  border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.cell-header {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.row-odd {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>Controls</section>
  <article>
    <aside>
      <div class="table">
        <div class="row row-odd">
          <div class="column cell-header">#</div>
          <div class="column cell-header">Make</div>
          <div class="column cell-header">Model</div>
          <div class="column cell-header">Year</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column" style="background-color: #FFB300">1</div>
          <div class="column">Honda</div>
          <div class="column">Accord</div>
          <div class="column">2009</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-odd">
          <div class="column" style="background-color: #803E75">2</div>
          <div class="column">Toyota</div>
          <div class="column">Camry</div>
          <div class="column">2012</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column" style="background-color: #FF6800">3</div>
          <div class="column">Hyundai</div>
          <div class="column">Elantra</div>
          <div class="column">2010</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-odd">
          <div class="column" style="background-color: #A6BDD7">4</div>
          <div class="column">Ford</div>
          <div class="column">Focus</div>
          <div class="column">2008</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column" style="background-color: #C10020">5</div>
          <div class="column">Nissan</div>
          <div class="column">Sentra</div>
          <div class="column">2011</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-odd">
          <div class="column" style="background-color: #CEA262">6</div>
          <div class="column">BMW</div>
          <div class="column">M3</div>
          <div class="column">2009</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column" style="background-color: #817066">7</div>
          <div class="column">Honda</div>
          <div class="column">Civic</div>
          <div class="column">2010</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-odd">
          <div class="column" style="background-color: #007D34">8</div>
          <div class="column">Kia</div>
          <div class="column">Soul</div>
          <div class="column">2010</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <div>
      <canvas width="985" height="223"></canvas>
    </div>
  </article>
  <section>Log</section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's the closest to what I'm after; also it looks correctly on IE/Firefox/Chrome. I still have a question how to fit a canvas in that, but I'll ask that separately. Let me digest your answer a little bit longer, I might need to ask a few clarifications.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh you welcome, Actually, I've took a look to my answer and notice that I had a rule that was doing nothing, so I updated my answer. making it cleaner. And I added the `canvas`

Comment: Almost perfect! The only think that I cannot figure out is the legend that should be a table. This is [my current jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg9btva2/). When the table is small enough it looks [like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/crfu3pkijkroi8n/37071838-01.png?dl=0). But as the table grows it starts overlapping with the log [like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g04fuip9ujtibhj/37071838-02.png?dl=0).

Comment: Sorry for mangling your styles and removing overflow-y, I just did know how to change them properly to make the rest of the table work. I also converted table to div as suggested elsewhere.

Comment: Ideally I want the scrollbar to appear when the table as long as on the latter picture. If that's too difficult, then permanent scrollbar will also do, but I can't seem to figure it out how to make it work with the table. Finally, note the legend width - it takes exactly as much as the content required and the rest is filled with the graph - this is ideal, want to keep it this way. But cannot to figure out how to make all these thing to work at the same time ;)

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because you already helped me immensely, but if you could also help me with this last bit I'll appreciate it even more!

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I just updated my answer,  to include your `table` take a look at `aside` rule

Comment: Just wanted to stop by to thank you again, I had to put this issue aside for a few days, but after a quick check your last change resolves the problem in my previous question. I wish I could upvote several times =)

Answer (score 0):

Well your code is a mess. Here is my attempt to clean it a bit and achieve what you described: https://jsfiddle.net/dckex2g7/

I assumed that top and bottom bars have fixed height which makes this a bit simpler. If they don't, you should use `display: flex; flex-direction: column` on body element and `flex-grow: 1` on .content.

Notice how I haven't used any JS for layout. To make it responsive you should use things like min-width and media queries. You almost never need JS for layout unless in a very few very specific cases which are not covered by flexbox somehow.

There's really a lot to describe about this solution so if you have any specific question ask away.

Comment: This is much better than my attempt, thanks!. Still in Chrome and IE there are unwanted both vertical and horizontal scrollbars. The Graph div spills out of visible area to the right. Also canvas, the same as in my example partially located outside of enclosing div and it's scaling (which you would have seen if you did not remove javascript that draws on it) is off. In firefox the table gets starched out vertically so it takes many screens.